# jQuery function with another

Tags: jquery

So I have the following function:

```
function SPAN(a,b){
    return '<span class="'+ a +'">'+ b +'</span>';
}
```

Then here is html that I am trying to turn into the function:

```
<span class="A">
    <span class="B">5</span>
    <span class="C">something</span>
</span>
```

Then here is what I got (of course, not working):

```
SPAN("A",{SPAN("B","5") SPAN("C","something");});
```

I know I got the syntax wrong, but could someone show me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using:

```
SPAN("A",SPAN("B","5") + SPAN("C","something"));
```

```js
function SPAN(a,b){
    return '<span class="'+ a +'">'+ b +'</span>';
}
alert(SPAN("A",SPAN("B","5") + SPAN("C","something")))
```

Comment: Ah, so, I need to use the plus sign. Thank you.! =)

Comment: @steveKim: yes. concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       function SPAN(a, b) {
           return '<span class="' + a + '">' + b + '</span>';
       }
       $('.content').html((SPAN("A", SPAN("B", "5") + SPAN("C", "something"))));
   });



<div class='content'> </div>
```